# GDB step is taking lot of time with clang

Tags: gdb, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am debugging a code in llvm/lib/.. . I am using debug build of clang. The break point is hitting by executing "clang ... -emit-llvm" command. I am able to attach gdb with it.

When I do step with gdb to move to next line it is taking lots of time. I tried to write a .gdbinit file by skipping all the symbols. But that did not resolve my issue. Please suggest me any ways to improve debugging speed.

Answer (score 0):

It was a VS code C++ extension issue. The issue is reported below :

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2901

At the time of answering this post the issue was not yet fixed. So as a work around I used "CodeLLDB" extension from VS code to use LLDB as debugger and stepping was very fast.